# While using Table Type data type in PL/SQL getting 'NO DATA FOUND' error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

Here defining a table type variable and trying to insert rows into that variable using for loop but unable to insert data . Getting data not found error... Please let me know whats wrong with this cod.

```
    DECLARE
TYPE T_EMP
IS
  TABLE OF EMP%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  V_EMP T_EMP ;
  V_MIN_EMP EMP.EMPNO%TYPE;
  V_MAX_EMP EMP.EMPNO%TYPE;
BEGIN
  --V_MIN_EMP:=7369;
  --V_MAX_EMP:=7934;
  SELECT MIN(empno) into V_MIN_EMP FROM EMP;
  SELECT MAX(EMPNO) INTO V_MAX_EMP FROM EMP;

  FOR I IN V_MIN_EMP..V_MAX_EMP
  LOOP
    SELECT * INTO V_EMP(I) FROM EMP WHERE EMPNO=I;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 4):

In your code `i` is an index.  It steps through the bounds monotonically.  So if your minimum EMPNO is 1234 and your maximum EMPNO is 5678 the values of `i` will be 1234, 1235, 1236 ... 5676, 5677, 5678.

But that probably is what you want to do, because EMPNO is likely to be a sparse array, with missing numbers.  So if you have no row in EMP where EMPNO=1235 your query will throw NO_DATA_FOUND.

What's the solution?  Use a bulk collect instead:

```
select * 
bulk collect into v_emp
from emp ;
```

That will select all the rows in the table, and it will be more efficient as well.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I botched the edit after reading the question :)

Comment: @Alex Poole                                                      _AFTER UR COMMENT I CHANGED MY CODE BUT AN ERROR IS THROWN SAYING TOO MANY VALUES_                                                   `DECLARE TYPE T_EMP IS TABLE OF EMP%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;  V_EMP T_EMP ;
--  V_MIN_EMP EMP.EMPNO%TYPE;
--  V_MAX_EMP EMP.EMPNO%TYPE;
BEGIN
  --V_MIN_EMP:=7369;
  --V_MAX_EMP:=7934;SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO V_EMP FROM SCOTT.emp;
END;`

Comment: @user2042156 - as far as I can see that's only possible if you're seeing two `EMP` tables, which would imply you are connected as someone other than `SCOTT`; so `T_EMP` is using your schema's `EMP` table, but you're selecting from `SCOTT`'s, and they must differ. Does it work if you make it `TABLE OF SCOTT.EMP%ROWTYPE`, or remove the `SCOTT.` from the `SELECT`?